# Nested object update doesn't trigger changedFeed event

Tags: rethinkdb

I have a table Users that contains a field avatar. This field is an object, example:

```
{
    "file": {
        "identifier":  "fafa2570-d642-4c78-912a-f275b70abed9" ,
        "mimeType":  "image/jpeg" ,
        "name":  "fafa2570-d642-4c78-912a-f275b70abed9.jpg"
    }
}
```

By default, when I create the user, the field avatar doesn't exist.
I can't trigger an action if the field avatar is updated. I tried:

```
rethinkdb.table(USER_TABLE_NAME)
.changes()
.filter(rethinkdb.row('old_val')('avatar').ne(rethinkdb.row('new_val')('avatar')))
.run((err, change) => {
    change.each((changeErr, { new_val }) => {
        // do my actions here ...
    });
});
```

Do you know the good query to get what I want ?
Thanks a lot :) !

Answer (score 0):

I found a way:

```
rethinkdb.table(USER_TABLE_NAME)
.changes()
.filter(
    (
        rethinkdb.row('old_val').hasFields({ avatar: true }).not()
        .and(rethinkdb.row('new_val').hasFields({ avatar: true }))
    )
    .or(
        rethinkdb.row('old_val').hasFields({ avatar: true })
        .and(rethinkdb.row('new_val').hasFields({ avatar: true }).not())
    )
    .or(
        rethinkdb.row('old_val')('avatar')('file')('identifier')
        .ne(rethinkdb.row('new_val')('avatar')('file')('identifier'))
    )
)
.run((err, change) => {
    change.each((changeErr, { new_val }) => {
        // do my actions here ...
    });
});
```

It's quite heavy but it does the job.